# Covariance Matrix of various $x,y,z$ (cartesian coordinates)

Tags: matrices, covariance

I have around 1000 values of gps receiver positions as follows: I have to calculate the covariance matrix with all these values.

All of the following values represent a SINGLE POINT.

[image: First few values]

How can I get a covariance matrix?

EDIT1:

What I have tried so far?

I know the formulae [image: covariance matrix]

Then I decided to find $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$

I know $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ formulae is this:

[image]

and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ I am trying to find using the following formulae:
[image]

Do you think this is the correct way to go? Do I need additional values to compute this.

Comment: @Shaun I have edited the doc to show where I am standing right now. I am confused and I only have x,y,z cooridnate data. And I have to computer covariance matrix.

Comment: Excellent. Don't worry about it now (since you're new) but [here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting future questions, answers, comments, etc. :)

Comment: @Shaun Can you please assist me on the question

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I'm not trained in Statistics enough to assist you without spending more time than I have available. I'm sorry. I just thought I'd help get used to the site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is the covariance matrix of the random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, where the random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ represent the stochastic processes that can produce the data you have collected. In your case they are the 3 coordinate positions recorded by the gps. The finite amount of data you have stored is a sampling of the population of all possible outcomes of the random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.

As you are dealing with a sampling (of about 1000 observations per coordinate/ random variable), then you should consider the [sample covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_sample_covariance), instead.

The number $N$ is the number of coordinate observations: in your case about 1000.
Any statistical software is able to compute the sample covariance matrix.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of statistical software which can compute covariance matrix.

Comment: R, Matlab, SPSS and even Excel